# Can we add hashing to firebase externally to the code?

Tags: c#, firebase

I am trying to build a personal project which is a hospital management system.
I am using firebase to store the database of the users and staff.
I checked that firebase does not require hashing as it already provides it.

Can I add the password hash to the code before it gets stored in the firebase database?
If I can, how can I do it?

I am using firebase to store the database of the users and staff.
I checked that firebase does not require hashing as it already provides it.
I am using C# for my project.

I want to hash the user's password to make it more secure before storing it in the firebase database.

Comment: Firebase is a suite of about 20 products, and you mention both a database and signing the user in - which are part of separate Firebase products. Can you edit your question (there's a link right under it) to clarify your question, specifically answering *why* you want to hash anything, and what data you're storing?

Comment: You can do whatever you want to to the data before it gets read or written, but Firebase won't help you with that. You'll have to write your own code.

Comment: You probably do not want to store passwords at all but just use firebase authentication as is. If you use firestore to store password hashes and then accidently misconfigure security rules, you could have a hash leak. Firebase authentication already meets major compliance certifications (https://firebase.google.com/support/privacy#firebase_is_certified_under_major_privacy_and_security_standards)